# How can I test this JavaScript effectively?

Tags: javascript, jquery, testing, bdd, jasmine

I've written a piece of code which acts on the event that a user highlights some text on a page. The code works fine (below) but my issue is how to test it effectively? Is there a way of mocking a user selecting text (specifically involving a `mouseup` event).

Maybe the issue is that checking if text is selected when a `mouseup` event occurs is not the best way to do this? Any insight is appreciated.

```
var note = {
  mouseHandler : function(e){
    selection = window.getSelection();
      if (selection.toString() !== '') {
       note.selection = selection;
       note.setAttributes();
       note.hideOverlay();
       note.placeOverlay();
    }
 }
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to trigger this with test code so I can ensure `note.placeOverlay()` happens

Comment: A very elementary method would be to execute a simple `alert()` at the end of the callback function `note.placeOverlay()`, or use `console.log('placeOverlay() is executed')`.

Comment: Terry: Let me clarify; I want to trigger the event automatically with code for the purpose of automated testing.
 
Bryan: Not really, it doesn't solve the issue of the event being triggered by a `mouseup`

Comment: Can't you just call `.mouseup()` on the element? http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/

Comment: Check out: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Answer (score 1):

So in Jasmine you would spy on `window.getSelection` and return a string in one case and none in the other. Then you would check that this what should happen  in `note.placeOver` happens.

```
spyOn(window, 'getSelection').andReturn('someString')
note.mouseHandler();
//test what you expect here


spyOn(window, 'getSelection').andReturn('')
note.mouseHandler();
//test that nothings happens here
```

*Maybe you can show what `note.placeOver` does, so I can complete the answer.*